# How to make regex only match when more than two groupings match?

Tags: regex, go

**How do I make quantifier only match if at least 2 of the grouped words are found?**

**I need this to match:**
`((?i:\bjack\b)|(?i:\bjill\b)|(?i:\bjohn\b)){2,}`

[image: https://i.imgur.com/sM2ZhW9.png]

**And I need this to not match:**

[image: https://i.imgur.com/V5eHOYi.png]

`Match if >= 2 of the words are found, in any order and case`

How do I go about doing that? After a few hrs I'm tired of reading regex. Thanks!

Comment: Since Go regex does not allow lookarounds, enumerate all alternatives, like `\b(?:jack\b.*\bjill|jill\b.*\bjack|jack\b.*\bjohn|john\b.*\bjack|john\b.*\bjill|jill\b.*\bjohn)\b`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rf5qYz/2).

Comment: I was really hoping to avoid that specific scenario, since adding 8 words ends you up with a crap load of variations.

Comment: Then either use a PCRE regex library in Go, or discard the regex approach like this.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't think this needs lookarounds, please see regex in my answer. Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: This could be much more easily and efficiently accomplished without regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```golang
re, _ := regexp.Compile(`\b(?i:jack|jill|john)\b`)
ma := re.FindAllString("Jill is friends with John. But Jack doesn't know.", -1)
if len(ma) < 2 //...then there aren't enough matches.
```

Alternatively, `(\b(?i:jack|jill|john)\b.*){2,}` does what you want, I think.

Comment: Holy moly, that actually worked. Did some modifications to fit what I needed, but it actually works with this (the alternative). I'm doing it through a bot written in .go so it has certain requirements, and it accepted this. Accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
((jack.*)|(john.*)|(jill.*)){2,}
```

will give a match for

jack and jill went up the hill

jack and john are in love

jill and john wreck the ideal home

but not for

john is privy to a dystopian vision

jack is eating onions